# Rails 3 ActiveRecord & Postgres: order by count on association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following 2 rails models:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :votes, through: :user

  default_scope includes(:user)

end
```

and

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :by, :for

  belongs_to :by, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :for, class_name: "User"

  validates :by, :for, presence: true

  validates_uniqueness_of(:by, scope: :for)
end
```

I'm trying to create a "top" scope on Profile which sorts the Profiles based on the number of "for" votes the associated user record has received

A vote is created by a user, for a user. The "by" column indicates the user who casted the vote, the "for" column indicates the user that has received a vote. I'm trying to get the profile of the user that has received the most votes.

This is what I've got so far:

```
   scope :top,
    select("profile.*, count(votes.id) AS votes_count").
    joins(:votes, :user).
    order("votes_count DESC")
```

This does not work with the following error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column
>   "votes_count" does not exist

It also doesn't take the "for" column into account

Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing a grouping, I believe.
Here's the query you're trying to do:

```
select profiles.*, count(votes.id) as votes_count 
  from profiles 
  left join votes on votes.for_id = profiles.user_id 
  group by profiles.id 
  order by votes_count desc;
```

So, let's turn this into an ActiveRecord scope:

```
scope :top, joins('left join votes on votes.for_id = profiles.user_id').
  select('profiles.*, count(votes.id) as votes_count').
  group('profiles.id').
  order('votes_count desc')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps a lot. I haven't changed profiles to profile, this was a mistake on my part.

Comment: This sort of works:   scope :top, joins('join votes on votes.for = profiles.user_id').
    select('profiles.*, count(votes.id) as votes_count').
    group('profiles.id').
    order('votes_count desc') but I seem to only get 1 profile, even-though I want a whole list sorted by the number of votes. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Do you only have one profile with any votes for its user? As written, the query would exclude any that didn't have any votes. Switch `join votes` for `left join votes` if you want to include profiles without any. (I've revised the answer to reflect this)

Comment: Thanks, I had a small mistake which only led me to have 1 result. Your initial answer was correct. Thanks again.

Comment: This works except that it removes records where it's associated records count is 0. Any way around that, to include the records whose associated records count is 0?

Comment: @Marc That should not happen - the use of a left join ensures that you get even the profiles that have no associated votes.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord way

```
Profile.joins(:votes).group("profiles.id").order("count(profiles.id) DESC")
```