# Count records from association's association - scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I have a `Country` which has many `Communities` which have many `Attractions`

```rb
# Country
has_many :communities

# Community
has_many :attractions

# Attraction
belongs_to :community
```

How can I construct a scope that is called from the `Country` which will give me all the attractions in its communities.

e.g. `@country.all_attractions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a `has_many`, `through` relation on your `Country` model:

```
# Country
has_many :communities
has_many :attractions, through: :communities

# Community
belongs_to :country
has_many :attractions

# Attraction
belongs_to :community
```

Then you can do:

```
@country.attractions
```

Comment: Hey Drenmi, thanks for that. Could you help me out with the `order.()` as well? I'm trying to order the communities by their attractions like so: `@communities = @country.communities.all.order('name asc').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)`

Comment: @TheMiniJohn: You want to order them by the number of attractions?

Comment: Yes. but I can't find a reference of how to do that.

Comment: @TheMiniJohn: There are some examples here on SO. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996618/rails-order-by-results-count-of-has-many-association. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696005/rails-3-activerecord-order-by-count-on-association, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478909/rails-3-activerecord-postgres-order-by-count-on-association.

Comment: I've read those but couldn't fit it into my case. I'm missing something :(